# Why do I get an error on this program that uses malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, valgrind

A program that ciphers a plaintext. key and value are passed into a function, and function returns a pointer. Not sure why compiler is screaming.

```
int main() {
  char *ciphertext = ciphering(key, plaintext);
  printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
  free(ciphertext);
}

char *ciphering(string key, string plaintext) {
  int n = strlen(plaintext);
  char *ciphertext = malloc(n + 1);

  // for loop fills in the cipher in ciphertext
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
      ciphertext[i] = toupper(key[(tolower(plaintext[i]) - 97)]);
    else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
      ciphertext[i] = tolower(key[(tolower(plaintext[i]) - 97)]);
    else
      ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
  }
  return ciphertext;
}
```

```
//==820==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
```

Comment: `ciphering` allocates some memory but doesn't store anything there, so it contains uninitialized garbage.  Did you forget to do `strcpy(ciphertext, plaintext)` or something like that?

Comment: The `ciphering` function doesn't actually write to the allocated memory. Hence it is uninitialised. I assume the code is not complete - if you keep going to complete the task that will resolve itself.

Comment: The `malloc` function doesn't initialize the memory it allocates. Its contents is *indeterminate* and may not even contain a string null-terminator.

Comment: Sorry, I try to condense my code for stackoverflow so as to not show all the unneccessary details, but I did write into the ciphertext. I'm not sure if you're allowed to do it like that because i know with pointers and such you have to initialize them to NULL if you're going to later assign them.

Comment: Please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). What is the subtraction with `97` supposed to do? And why are you doing the exact same thing in both the `isupper` and `islower` case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to null terminate the generated string.

```
char *ciphertext = malloc(n + 1);
ciphertext[n] = '\0';
```

Comment: yes! You are totally right, I forget C doesn't automatically do it for you. Thank you

Comment: @FranciscoGutierrezRamirez I wouldn't say its about C, `malloc` specifcally allocates memory that is uninitialized. `calloc` zero-initializes memory it allocates so you wouldn't have to manually put `'\0'` then.